# How can i update field called 'Value' in SQL? i need to make it 15% less

Tags: sql, ms-access

ive tried update other fields and it worked just fine in this format but when i try to update the value field i get "syntax error in UPDATE statement"
the code is:

```
UPDATE Boxes
    SET VALUE = VALUE * 0.85;
```

ive tried put '' and () in a few forms, 
tried to set value to numbers
tried remove the 'SET' for some reason :O
dont know what to do

[image]

Comment: Your syntax looks fine.  Is it possible that the trailing semicolon is causing a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VALUE` is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Access-reserved-words-and-symbols-AE9D9ADA-3255-4B12-91A9-F855BDD9C5A2) and it should be quoted with square brackets:

```
UPDATE Boxes
SET [VALUE] = [VALUE] * 0.85;
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively as [@Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422451/parfait) commented:

```
UPDATE Boxes
SET `VALUE` = `VALUE` * 0.85;
```

Comment: @BarElimelech Great to hear that. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Access also supports backticks like MySQL for escaping reserved words or spaces/symbols.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for pointing it. I haven't used MS Access for ages :)